# Disable all system fn+letter keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, mission-control, emacs

I have the fn key set up as the Meta key for Emacs. But recently Mac OS (both 12.0.1 and 12.1) has started gobbling one or two combinations of fn plus a letter key: most notably, fn+N opens Notification Centre, even though I have no shortcut set up for ‘Show Notification Centre’ in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Mission Control. Since a lot of Emacs modes use `M-n` to mean ‘next’, this makes those shortcuts in Emacs unusable.

I never use the systemwide fn-shortcuts. How do I defang them completely?

Comment: Since this keyboard shortcut is undocumented, apparently unchangeable, and appears to conflict with the intent of the option provided in System Preferences, I have reported the issue to Apple with Feedback Assistant. Hopefully they will change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the same. I thought setting (ns-function-modifier 'control) in emacsforosx will overlap Monterey OS system fn binding but it's not that like with previous osx versions.

We'll see if there's some response from Apple.

Comment: I have worked around this for now by providing keyboard-macro alternatives to all the offending system keyboard shortcuts I could find with ⌥⇧ plus the letter in question https://gitlab.com/dpk/dotfiles/-/commit/d9b11280ecc50aead720f2b3ad02b8298f5b9bce

Comment: What worked for me: I installed Karabiner-Elements and in System Preferences / Keyboard / Modifier Keys set Global Key: Control for Karabiner DriverKit 1.6.0.